# Writing the Real Part of Complex Integrand

Tags: complex-analysis, laplace-transform, contour-integration, riemann-integration, inverse-laplace

I'm having a hard time to understand how's Eq. $(6.73)$ become Eq. $(6.75)$. It's taken from *Numerical Methods for Laplace Transform Inversion* by Cohen.
Here's the problem:

> [...]. The basis of their formulation is, like Talbot, that the inverse transform is given by
> $$f(t)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}e^{st}\bar f(s)ds.\tag{6.71}$$
> The contour is deformed by means of the path
> $$s(\theta)=r\theta(\cot\theta+i),\quad-\pi<\theta<\pi,\tag{6.72}$$
> where $r$ is a parameter. This path only involves one parameter whereas Talbot's consisted of two. Integration over the deformed path yields
> $$f(t)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{-\pi}^\pi e^{ts(\theta)}\bar f(s(\theta))s'(\theta)d\theta.\tag{6.73}$$
> Differentiating (6.72) we have $s'(\theta)=ir(1+i\sigma(\theta))$, where
> $$\sigma(\theta)=\theta+(\theta\cot\theta-1)\cot\theta.\tag{6.74}$$
> We find
> $$f(t)=\frac{r}{\pi}\int_0^\pi\Re\Bigl[e^{ts(\theta)}\bar f(s(\theta))(1+i\sigma(\theta))\Bigr]d\theta.\tag{6.75}$$

As you can see there, i'm confused about where the $\Re$ got from. And i have 2 speculations about this.

**Speculation 1** (The idea is originated from my friend, so let me rewrite what he said)

Regarding the integral: $s(\theta)$ on $(-\pi,\,\pi)$ is symmetric about $\theta=0$ (i don't understand this part). So we can integrate on $\theta\in (0,\pi)$ and multiply by $2$ in the denominator of the constant (outside the integral). The factor $ir$ in $s'(\theta)$ cancels the $i$ in the constant and gives it $r$ in the numerator.

Assuming $f(t)$ is a real-valued function, $f(t)=\Re f(t)$. For Riemann integrable functions $g(z)$, we have $\Re \int g(z)\Bbb dz = \int \Re g(z) \Bbb dz$. Hence, since $f(t)$ is equal to an integral, we can take $\Re$ on both sides and move the real part symbol inside the integral.

**Speculation 2** (This is my own idea)

By letting the whole integrand with $\Lambda$ for simplification purpose (i'm not performing change of variable here, just for a simplification). Then we can consider:

$$\begin{align}
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \Lambda\,\Bbb d\Lambda &= \int_{-\pi}^{0} \Lambda\,\Bbb d\Lambda + \int_{0}^{\pi} \Lambda\,\Bbb d\Lambda\\
&= -\int_{0}^{-\pi} \Lambda\,\Bbb d\Lambda + \int_{0}^{\pi} \Lambda\,\Bbb d\Lambda\\
&= \int_{0}^{\pi} \overline{\Lambda}\,\Bbb d\overline{\Lambda} + \int_{0}^{\pi} \Lambda\,\Bbb d\Lambda\\
&= 2\int_{0}^{\pi}\Re \Lambda\,\Bbb d \Lambda
\end{align}$$

The last expression is considering this property : $z + \overline{z} = 2\Re z$, where $\overline{z}$ is the conjugate of $z$. But i'm not really sure if i can consider the third line is valid about the conjugate? And by the way. The first equation on the picture is the formula for finding the Inverse Laplace Transform of $f(t)$ (real-valued) and the Laplace transform that what i'm talking is one-sided Laplace Transform.

Are both speculations correct? Is my speculation is correct? If not, please provide the correct interpretation behind the story of Eq. $(6.73)$ become Eq. $(6.75)$. Please kindly to help me, i really need your help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would say that your speculation 2 is correct noting that $d\theta$ is a real measure so is conjugate invariant and of course there is the symmetry that the integrand on $[-\pi,0]$ becomes the conjugate of the integrand on $[0, \pi]$ under $\theta \to -\theta$ which checks out easily

Comment: @Conrad Ok Thanks. And btw what about the singularities that originated from Bromwich contour? Are those singularities stay at the same place and the only one is deformed is the contour itself?

Comment: not sure of the question in relation with your post - if you accept 6.73, then the discussion above explains how one gets 6.75 from it and that I thought was your question (how you get from 6.73 to 6.75) not why 6.73 is correct which is something different